# what does it mean to refer to assembly in following manner

Tags: c#

```
assemblyname.assemblyname myobj = new assemblyname.assemblyname()
```

I have seen that assembly are used this way, why?

as i have seen it being used as such as well

```
assemblyname myobj = new assemblyname()
```

sample code is as such

```
Using CreateUsers;

CreateUsers.CreateUsers userCreation= new CreateUsers.CreateUsers();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are confusing the *namespace* name with the *assembly* name. Generally the top-level namespace is also the assembly name.

Answer (score 1):

You mean namespace, not assembly name - those are totally different things.

I will explain with example.

When you have `using System.IO;` on top of the code, you can have `StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("path here");` instead of `System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader("path here");` as the namespace `System.IO` is already "known" to the compiler.

You can still have the full reference (e.g. `System.IO.StreamReader`) even when including the namespace, it won't throw any error and can be useful for readability and sometimes required when there's conflict, meaning you include two namespaces both contain class with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

The first code explicitly specifies the namespace of the class and the second one doesn't. The second code requires an additional `using assemblyname;` directive at the top of the file.

Comment: Daniel, on a sample code i am trying to understand, they do have the using assemblyname on top of the file and still using assemblyname.assemblyname myobj = new assemblyname.assemblyname(). hence the confusion.

Comment: Then it's just redundant. But it doesn't hurt either.

Comment: oki. So if i were to get a new build of the assembly from developer, and add it to my bin directory, my code should compile fine, as far as the initailization is concerned?

Comment: As long as he doesn't change its namespaces, the will be no problem.

Comment: he gave me a new assembly build with no namespace change, but the way his code is referring to his assembly no longer works now...maybe open a new post/thread

Answer (score 0):

This can't be the real assembly name. It was the namespace.